# What is the difference between how objects are handled in Dapper and Entity Framework - with raw SQL queries?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, orm, asp.net-core, dapper

From my reading, Dapper is suppose to be more SQL friendly, but Entity Framework (EF) allows raw SQL.  I typically use SQL, but I like some of the things in EF.  Many of my queries are fairly complex, cover more than one database and database engine, and most are not just simple CRUD.

When it comes to using SQL, what is the difference in how an object is handled?  When I issue a query, if something comes back and I assign it to a `<dynamic>` `List` type, are they both the same?

I am using ASP.NET Core 1.x.

Comment: I'm a little curious about how you can "like some of the things in EF"? EF is an all-encompassing picture. Which little bits have you managed to isolate and like?

Comment: In terms of performance, there is not as much difference between EF Core 2 and Dapper as there used to be: https://medium.com/@engr.mmohsin/entity-framework-core-2-dapper-performance-benchmark-c29e8cce9e1b

Answer (score 1):

There may be some performance differences between the two but with raw SQL queries both will populate your IList (of whatever) just the same.  If you are planning to write your own complex SQL for most/all database interaction then dapper may be a better choice for you since it doesn't come with all the overhead of EF. On the other hand, if you want to take advantage of things like Code First Migrations, change tracking, etc. or you intend to do most of your database work in code (not raw SQL) then EF makes sense.

That said, your best bet may be to spend a little time with both. You may find it won't take long to make a decision once you start playing with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using EF to issue SQL requests, you're not really using EF. The calls are line for line equivalent to ADO, and the loading of the result object, which you get to define and maintain, is trivial. Lots of folk use EF, but then use Dapper for the times they want to do raw SQL. Dapper caches the mapping of the result-set to POCO, so subsequent queries run faster. I don't think EF does this. Also the parameter handling is *much* nicer in Dapper.

But you're still stuck with SQL in string literals, every error is a runtime error and you have to write and maintain your result POCOs. I contend you'll be happier and live longer if you use [QueryFirst](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ69yVxtrRAhWGVxQKHfHFD68QFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.visualstudio.com%2Fitems%3FitemName%3Dbbsimonbb.QueryFirst&usg=AFQjCNFSA_xLr3tZuEPX04vM47n4iRLTbg&sig2=5nzyALac1qBfYokGIOzcXQ) (disclaimer: which I wrote). Your SQL in a .sql file, syntax validated as you type. Your POCOs generated at design time from your query results. Your queries continually integration tested, and [*numerous other benefits*](http://geniusorfantasist.blogspot.fr/) which I'll be documenting shortly!